# Actively handling background events in Node.js

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm currently trying to handle background events.

When a user gets temporarily banned, we store the ban expiration in our database so that we can use it to unban them at the right time. My current code every 10 seconds goes through every single ban and checks if the user should get unbanned, but I know already that doing like this will stop working properly with a large number of users.

The solution I was thinking of was about caching every single ban after starting the code, but it seems extremely unoptimized and I feel like `setTimeout` isn't the best option.

Would it be possible to track all the bans and actively send events to my code to perform more actions?

Answer (score 0):

something you could try is save the to_unbanned timestamp and make queries in the database for all users that must be unbanned (when to_unbanned is equal or less than now)

and for your question

> Would it be possible to track all the bans and actively send events to my code to perform more actions?

yes, you can use [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-event-emitter) in nodejs